# not able to display fetch value from database in devextreme dxDataGrid

Tags: jquery, json, devexpress, devextreme

i am new to **devextreme dxDataGrid** i am fetching value form database using json my **var objdata**  storing data in json string format and i am passing **var objdata** as **datasource in dxDataGrid** but **i am getting bad request error in dxDataGrid** below is image of json string in my **var objdata** any help will be appreciated

[image: picture]

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
     fetchrecord();
   });

   function fetchrecord() { // calling fetch function
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Default.aspx/fetchemp",
       data: '{}',
       contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: OnSuccess,
       error: OnErrorCall
     });

     function OnSuccess(response) {
       var objdata = (response.d); // storing data in json string format
       $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
         allowColumnReordering: true,
         allowColumnResizing: true,
         columnChooser: {
           enabled: true
         },
         columnFixing: {
           enabled: true
         },
         filterRow: {
           visible: true,
           applyFilter: "auto"
         },
         searchPanel: {
           visible: true,
           width: 240,
           placeholder: "Search..."
         },
         dataSource: objdata,
         columns: ["ID", "Name", "Gender", "Pincode", "City"]

       });



     }

     function OnErrorCall(response) {
       alert("error occur");
     }


   }
```

```html
<div class="demo-container">
  <div id="gridContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to update the `columns` option according to your json. I mean it should be like this `columns: ["Id", "name", "gender", "pincode", "City"]`.

Comment: @Sergey http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134801/dxdatagrid-how-to-refresh-the-widget  can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data that comes with the names on your side are not the same because you have made a typing mistake.

> You have to do it this way.

```
columns:["Id", "name", "gender", "pincode", "City"]
```

> or

```
     columns: [
     { dataField:'Id',    caption: 'ID'},
     { dataField:'name',   caption: 'Name'},
     { dataField:'gender',caption: 'Gender'},
     { dataField:'pincode',caption: 'Pincode'},
     { dataField:'City'}],
```