# dxDataGrid - How to refresh the widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, devextreme

When ı clicked button, not working refresh.If the purpose is to add to the database buton button press to come to the screen. But is not updating. I created a datagrid with ajax. I also wrote the refresh function in ViewModel.What may be the reason for not renewing. My data is json.

```js
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/data/orderItems"
        success: function (msg, result, status, xhr) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
        $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
        dataSource: obj,
        filterRow: {
        visible: true}});}});
        var viewModel = {
        refresh: function () {        
        var dataGrid = $('#gridContainer').dxDataGrid('instance');
        dataGrid.refresh();}};
return viewModel;
```

```html
<div data-options="dxView : { name: 'dd',disableCache: true } " >
   <div data-bind="dxCommand: { icon: 'refresh', id: 'save', onExecute: refresh }"></div>
     <div  data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } " >
       
         <div  id="gridContainer"></div> 
        
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of calling the refresh method for the data grid instance? Do you change a dynamically changed data source ? What do you expect from calling the refresh method? If you initialize the grid in your ajax call just once, it does not make any sense to refresh the grid.

Comment: @AlexSkorkin Can I ask you a question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Alex mentioned, your ajax happens only one. So, it's better to use the [DataSource configuration object](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#dataSource) to load data:

```
var dataSource = {
    load: function() {
        var items = $.Deferred();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/data/orderItems",
            success: function(result) {
                items.resolve(result.items);
            }
        });

        return items.promise();
    }
};

$("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    //...
});
```

Then, if you call the `refresh()` method of dxDataGrid, data source will be reloaded.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k3uu2sxs/)

Pay attention, the [refresh](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Methods/#refresh) method is useful if your data source is changing dynamically.

Comment: This method is not working. Only ajax works. how will I do?

Comment: > What do you expect from calling the refresh method?

Comment: I will briefly explain. I delete the line with the dialog on the screen when I press on the line. But the line stays there. But it does not immediately fall on the screen. I made a refresh button for this. Go on the screen in the press. (It is not in my code)

Comment: It looks like you have a bug here - "I delete the line with the dialog on the screen when I press on the line. But the line stays there." Be sure you delete a row correctly.

Comment: So if you look at it, I do it with ajax. I get the row id and send it with ajax. It is done with web service. I'm just sending the row id and seeing the length of the data goes down.

Comment: Take a look at this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/sergfry/f8rq82af/2/). I use local data, but it makes not difference. BTW, dxDataGrid has built-in editing functionality - https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/editing/#allowDeleting

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I will try to reach the end with what you gave.